# Explanation for a latex def

Tags: latex, xelatex

I came across this line in the awesome-cv document class

```
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
   \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1#2#3}}{#1#2#3}%
}

\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{16pt}
   {1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
```

What it does is that you give it a word and it changes the colour of the first three letters of the word.

However, I don't understand how it works. Could someone please describe it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without considering the definitions in their entirety, focus on the following:

```
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  % <some definition>
}

\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{%
  % <some definition>
  \@sectioncolor #1}}
```

It should be obvious that `\sectionstyle` takes a single, mandatory argument. This mandatory argument is the title of the section, as in `\sectionstyle{Education}` for example. This argument is passed to `\@sectioncolor` via

```
\@sectioncolor #1
```

However, note that there are no braces around `#1`, since `\@sectioncolor` expects *three* mandatory arguments. To that end, a call like `\sectionstyle{Education}` translates to

```
\@sectioncolor Education
```

where `\@sectioncolor` takes the first three *tokens* as its mandatory argument. That is, one can almost assume the following transferred input:

```
\@sectioncolor {E}{d}{u}cation
```

Within `\@sectioncolor`'s definition, `E` would be `#1`, `d` would be `#2` and `u` would be `#3`. They are set in sequence `#1#2#3` if you don't want your sections highlighted by colour, or they're coloured using the colour `awesome` if you do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is this behavior only for def or does the same happen with newcommand?

Comment: @Ashkan: The same would happen with `\newcommand{\@sectioncolor}[3]{...}`.